# Strange iCloud Login issue

Tags: icloud

Okay, so I'm pretty sure i have this right because i have tried a bunch of fixes over the past few days to get to this conclusion.

I think my IP address is for some reason being denied access to Apple servers.

I am able to sign into iCloud via my cellular connection.

But the moment I try to access or login to any of iCloud login (on mac/phone/windows pc) via my wifi (static IP) apple cannot sign me in and returns the error "unable to connect to server" or similar ones.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

NB: I have done everything from router reset to fresh install of OS. in fact, when I was doing the install, I had to switch between mobile hotspot and wifi to ensure Apple verified my credentials and let me begin the install in the first place. Because over wifi, I couldn't even get El Capitan to download.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to investigate your firewall settings on your router, or ask your ISP if they know of any particular ports that may be blocked & how to change that.

The list of ports & services required for all software Apple access is fairly substantial, but is all detailed at Apple's Knowledge Base: [TCP and UDP ports used by Apple software products](https://support.apple.com/HT202944)

Comment: I checked but I'm sure thats not it. Almost everything was accessible just a few days ago. If it helps, why i feel apple may have blocked my IP is because, i tried a fresh install of mac os 2 days ago but had to do it twice since mc pc lost power during the install. I read somewhere that apple blacklists IPs due to heavy download

Comment: Twice is not a heavy download (also your iPhone would be on the same IP when on WiFi and is not blocked so can't really be Apple) - however if you think Apple has blocked you the only way out is constant Apple

Comment: Iphone was not on wifi. I had to disconnect and use my 3g network as a hotspot to get it to work.

Comment: and spoke to Apple, they don't know why.

Comment: Apple wouldn't know why - your ISP might, though

Comment: Update:- Here's what i know so far. I am able to use iCloud and all related services on the same system using a proxy. So switching the IP does work. I have to tell my ISP now to change my static IP as that appears to be the only solution.